# Problem exporting and importing articles within two Joomla 4 installation via Mysql

Tags: mysql, joomla

via mysql database, I am trying to export articles from a Joomla 4  installation to another joomla 4 installation, but I can figured it out.

I've copied these tables of the joomla4 database:

jos_content
jos_contentitem_tag_map
jos_content_frontpage
jos_content_rating
jos_content_types

Than I have imported into another fresh Joomla4 installation, I can see the articles that are imported in the new database but from the backoffice I can't see any articles there.
Maybe I forgot to export some necessary table?

I use the same way to import menus and modules, and it works fine, but when with the articles it does not work.

Does anyone can help me?
Many thanks.

Filippo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed off the categories table? Do the categories match up?

Also, check the access rights too. The groups/levels maybe different and you are not assigned to the rights that are assigned to the imported articles.

I would tend to advise using CSVI to export/import too as this maps the field etc accordingly without a DB Export/Import.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
All tables concerning categories has been exported too.

Comment: and the DB category map?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to empty the target database, copy **all** the tables to that installation, and then see if it works. If you want to make some modifications to the target database/website, then do it after copying all the tables. This is a cleaner approach than copying a few tables if the target website is just empty.